# How to display every message in a thread with at least one new message?

Tags: mutt

I currently have a macro to quickly show only new messages:

```
macro index ,sn "l ^a^k~N\n"  "show only new messages"
```

However, this macro loses the context for new messages in ongoing threads.  I would like to be able to modify it so that I'm able to display every message from a thread that has at least one new message in it.  I've read the [mutt manual](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/) a few times, but I don't see an obvious way to achieve this using standard limit patterns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the following pattern: `~(~N)`. More generally:

```
~(PATTERN) messages in threads containing messages matching PATTERN,
e.g. all threads containing messages from you: ~(~P)
```

Note: This was added in some Mutt 1.5.x release. And here's the [part of the corresponding manual on patterns](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#patterns-modifier).

Comment: Of course I would be looking at the wrong documentation...  Thanks so much for the answer!